# Add new column with row wise maximum on multiple conditions of other columns

Tags: r

This should be fairly easy but I'm just confusing myself. With data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, rate1 = c(1, 0, 0.3, 0.5, 1)
, rate2 = c(0, 0.6, 1, 0, 1), cost1 = 3:7, cost2 = 8:4)
```

I want to add a new column according to whether `rate1` or `rate2` is equal to 1 then fill in the new column with maximum value of `cost1` and `cost2` otherwise use 0. The desired result will be:

```
  id rate1 rate2 cost1 cost2 overspent
1  1   1.0   0.0     3     8         8
2  2   0.0   0.6     4     7         0
3  3   0.3   1.0     5     6         6
4  4   0.5   0.0     6     5         0
5  5   1.0   1.0     7     4         7
```

I assume using something similar to:

```
df$overspent <- with(df, ifelse((rate1 == 1 || rate2 == 1)
                     , apply(cbind(cost1, cost2), 1, max), 0))
```

but apparently it does not work. Please correct me. Thanks!

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal for advice regarding equality of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `|`, not `||`. But see how this is a bit more elegant:

```
transform(df, overspent = ifelse(rate1 == 1 | rate2 == 1,
                                 pmax(cost1, cost2), 0))
```

Also, as @Ferdinand.kraft points out, comparing numerics might be dangerous (not in this example though) so you might want to replace things like `rate1 == 1` with:

```
abs(rate1 - 1) < .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5
```

or

```
sapply(rate1 - 1, function(x)isTRUE(all.equal(x, 0)))
```